# GCE and Kubernetes permissions

Tags: kubernetes, google-compute-engine

I'm trying to setup via script a kubernetes cluster on GCE, which always worked for the past, but I created a new project on GCE and I suddenly get all these permissions errors:

Example:

```
Error from server (Forbidden): serviceaccounts is forbidden: User "client" cannot list serviceaccounts in the namespace "default": Unknown user "client"
```

Also when I `kubectl proxy` and open http://localhost:8001/ I get:

```
{
  "kind": "Status",
  "apiVersion": "v1",
  "metadata": {

  },
  "status": "Failure",
  "message": "forbidden: User \"client\" cannot get path \"/\": Unknown user \"client\"",
  "reason": "Forbidden",
  "details": {

  },
  "code": 403
}
```

Could somebody hint me please into the right direction? Thx!

Comment: RBAC is on by default. You will need to create Role and RoleBindings for the "client" user you are authenticating with.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49075723/what-does-unknown-user-client-mean

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate of [what does Unknown user "client" mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49075723/what-does-unknown-user-client-mean):

Found out there is some issue with gcloud config. This command solved it:

`gcloud config unset container/use_client_certificate`