# kubectl get pods fails after authentication

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm randomly getting this error today for `kubectl get pods`:

```
Error from server (Forbidden): pods is forbidden: User "client" cannot list pods in the namespace "default": Unknown user "client"
```

The only significant change that occurred is I started minikube earlier.

The error message occurs after I run:

```
gcloud container clusters get-credentials wordpress --zone europe-west1-b --project example
```

What is the cause of this error? What does this 'client' user refer to - is it a service account?

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/49094802/1663462

```
gcloud config unset container/use_client_certificate
gcloud container clusters get-credentials wordpress --zone europe-west1-b --project example
```