# Kubernetes - Error from server (Forbidden): ... is forbidden:

Tags: kubernetes, gcloud, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm trying to follow [this](https://medium.com/google-cloud/back-to-microservices-with-istio-p1-827c872daa53) istio tutorial, while I use google cloud.
After I ran the istio.yaml, I got the following error:

```
Error from server (Forbidden): error when creating "istio.yaml": clusterroles.rbac.authorization.k8s.io "istio-sidecar-injector-default" is forbidden: attempt to grant extra privileges
```

After looking online, I saw [a solution on github community](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/42559):

```
For the benefit of others who might run into this issue, I worked around the problem by running:

$ gcloud config set container/use_client_certificate True
$ export CLOUDSDK_CONTAINER_USE_CLIENT_CERTIFICATE=True

Before running $ gcloud container clusters get-credentials ...
```

After I tried this solution, I got `forbidden` error for almost every command, i.e.:

```
$ kubectl get pods
Error from server (Forbidden): pods is forbidden: User "client" cannot list pods in the namespace "default"
$ kubectl get namespaces
Error from server (Forbidden): namespaces is forbidden: User "client" cannot list namespaces at the cluster scope
```

I tried use the solution on [this stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49075723/what-does-unknown-user-client-mean/49094802#49094802), so I ran:

```
$gcloud config unset container/use_client_certificate
$gcloud container clusters get-credentials my-cluster
```

But I still got the forbidden error. Any idea?

Comment: The original error is just a missing clusterrolebinding, you'll need to identify which one is missing. The work around doesn't really address the missing binding. If you'd rather not deal with RBAC, you can return to ABAC using [gcloud container clusters update CLUSTER_NAME --enable-legacy-authorization](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/container/clusters/update#--enable-legacy-authorization)

Comment: You need to create service account which gives cluster rolebinding access, after creating you can configure kubectl with that service account.