# terraform (0.11 and 0.12) apply works on 1 machine, but not on the other

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, google-kubernetes-engine

Working on 2 different windows 10 machines where 'terraform apply' works on one machine, but not on the other. Before moving to the second pc, i completely removed the infrastructure on gcp, and made sure i only kopied the tf file + the essential json. (no state files etc. ) Since preparing this for pipeline, i want to have a clean environment to start with

codesnippit (Full script at the end, further below):

```
provider "kubernetes" {
  host     = "https://${google_container_cluster.primary.endpoint}"
  username = "${var.username}"
  password = "${var.password}"
  client_certificate = "${base64decode(google_container_cluster.primary.master_auth[0].client_certificate)}"
  client_key = "${base64decode(google_container_cluster.primary.master_auth[0].client_key)}"
  cluster_ca_certificate = "${base64decode(google_container_cluster.primary.master_auth[0].cluster_ca_certificate)}"
  version = "~> 1.7"
}

# Namespace
resource "kubernetes_namespace" "testspace" {
  metadata {
    annotations = {
      name = "testspace"
    }
    name = "testspace"
  }
}
```

According to all examples i see, this should work, and it does, on my laptop, but on my second machine i get the following error:

```
Error: Failed to configure: username/password or bearer token may be set, but not both

  on Deploy_Test.tf line 1, in provider "kubernetes":
   1: provider "kubernetes" {
```

If I remove the username and password, the error disapears, but I can't create a namespace because i have no authorization? the error states:

```
Error: namespaces is forbidden: User "client" cannot create namespaces at the cluster scope
```

and now i'm getting a bit lost: This code runs fine on one pc, but not on the other, and i can't figure out why. When redploying this again from pc one, after starting in a new clean terraform folder 
Hopefully someone has an idea where to look  ?

Tried the following so far:
updated to 0.12.1 - no difference.
downgraded to 0.11 -  no difference.
Tried all different combinations of using certificate, or username/pw combo

```
provider "google" {
  credentials = file("account.json")
  project     = var.project
  region      = var.region
  version =  "~> 2.7"
}

resource "google_container_cluster" "primary" {
  name               = "${var.name}-cluster"
  location           = var.region
  initial_node_count = 1
  master_auth {
    username = var.username
    password = var.password
    /*
    client_certificate_config {
      issue_client_certificate = true
    }
    */
  }
  node_version       = "1.11.10-gke.4"
  min_master_version = "1.11.10-gke.4"
  node_config {
    preemptible  = true
    machine_type = "n1-standard-1"

    metadata = {
      disable-legacy-endpoints = "true"
    }

    oauth_scopes = [
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/compute",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/logging.write",
      "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/monitoring",
    ]
  }
}
provider "kubernetes" {
  host     = "https://${google_container_cluster.primary.endpoint}"
  username = "${var.username}"
  password = "${var.password}"
  client_certificate = "${base64decode(google_container_cluster.primary.master_auth[0].client_certificate)}"
  client_key = "${base64decode(google_container_cluster.primary.master_auth[0].client_key)}"
  cluster_ca_certificate = "${base64decode(google_container_cluster.primary.master_auth[0].cluster_ca_certificate)}"
  version = "~> 1.7"
}

# Namespace
resource "kubernetes_namespace" "testspace" {
  metadata {
    annotations = {
      name = "testspace"
    }
    name = "testspace"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems here, first:

> Error: Failed to configure: username/password or bearer token may be set, but not both

is telling you that you can EITHER authenticate with username and password, OR with a bearer token. Your error appears to be sourced from here, first:

```
provider "kubernetes" {
  host     = "https://${google_container_cluster.primary.endpoint}"
  username = "${var.username}"
  password = "${var.password}"
  client_certificate = "${base64decode(google_container_cluster.primary.master_auth[0].client_certificate)}"
  client_key = "${base64decode(google_container_cluster.primary.master_auth[0].client_key)}"
  cluster_ca_certificate = "${base64decode(google_container_cluster.primary.master_auth[0].cluster_ca_certificate)}"
  version = "~> 1.7"
}
```

Basically you're pointing at the three .pem files AND you're trying to auth with user/pass. Choose one or the other. See [this page](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/kubernetes/index.html) about the kubernetes provider (Specifically "Statically defined credentials") for details about that particular error.

That said:

> Error: namespaces is forbidden: User "client" cannot create namespaces at the cluster scope

Is telling you that you don't have the permissions to do what you're trying to do. Once you can identify what it's trying to authenticate as, you can identify what is wrong. What it appears to be is that your client_certificate, client_key, and/or cluster_ca_certificate are out of date on the second computer, but not the first. I believe it should be the cluster_ca_certificate that's out of date, if your `gcloud config set container/use_client_certificate` is true. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49075723/what-does-unknown-user-client-mean/49094802#49094802) has more information about that.

If that's not the case, we will have to investigate further.

Comment: Thanks J. Olsson for your quick response,  I don't see how the google provider credentials are related to the authentication on the kubernetes provider, with the error stating:  ```Error: Failed to configure: username/password or bearer token may be set, but not both

  on Deploy_Test.tf line 1, in provider "kubernetes":```but will try as You suggested. But, the reason why i posted this question is: Why is it working on one machine, (laptop) and not on the other. The script as posted gives me  no error when running from my Win10 laptop, but using another win10 machine it shows these errors

Comment: Oh, apologies. I answered when I was quite sleepy, and definitely just grabbed the first "provider" block and answered the wrong question.

The issue is related to [statically defined credentials](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/kubernetes/index.html) or should be. My feeling is that your .pem files on the second computer are out of date, while they're correct on the first.

Comment: in a bit of an update, i fired up a linux Vm on the not working pc, and i can run the code there as well. Which leads me to believe it is not a code issue, but a terraform vs PC issue.  Using the same credentials btw (file.json) to authenticate to GCP, so the only question left is: why do i get the error message ```Error: Failed to configure: username/password or bearer token may be set, but not both``` on this pc.

Comment: I just remember, i installed Docker Desktop a while back, and uninstalled it after use.  Just verified this, and there's no docker, or kubectl left. But it might have left same traces like a default kubectl config context, gonna try and find some left over registry junk

Comment: Yes, this is very ... interesting ... as an issue. It should be that only one of the two is set (the keys or the user/pass), but since it works with both on your other computer, it should work here. I won't lie - I'm somewhat stumped, despite sounding pretty confident in my answer. I'll keep thinking about it.

Answer (score 0):

Found the cause of this: 
Previously i've had Docker Desktop installed. After removal, it has left some junk, in this case on c:\users\%username% there was a .kube folder left with a kube config file in there, containing the used certificates.
I zipped the folder content, and removed the folder. After that terraform works similar as on the other machines.